# How to add my MFT at the end of the topology resolved by the media session?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I need to insert my MFT before the EVR and after the very last MFT that the media session resolved. I want to take uncompressed/decoded input and apply a blur filter to it and send it to the EVR/window to be displayed. I need to take advantage of the job media session already did, I don't want to resolve dependencies myself. I need to know what options I have in order to further investigate on google?

Comment: Just to verify that I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting to create a video stream with the following flow: source->mft->blur filter mft->evr?  However you don't want to do the media type negotiation between elements?

Comment: source-------compressed stream-------->(any combination of mfts)-----uncompressed stream----->blur filter->evr

Comment: Why don't you do your blur filter processing in a custom IMFTransform and include it within the topology according to your provided flow? That's probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: Did you find the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a partial topology. After that you need to implement a custom topology loader. In Load method after loading the topology you can insert your MFT and insert it between the last MFT and EVR. Disconnect tem first. 
Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250372(v=vs.85).aspx